# How to separate between training and testing data in Random Forest that sourced from two different data set

Tags: python, pandas, random-forest

I developed a random forest to make a prediction of vehicle vibration. I have two separate data frames in which I want to assign one of them as my training data while the other one as my testing data.

How can I do this in python?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet to show what you've done so far? The description of the question is not enough to go on